# Filter wordpress query with SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to create a custom filter for the wordpress posts query. I tested the SQL query, and it returns the posts. When added to the parse_query hook it generates an SQL sytax error. I think it's too complex to use the query_vars. In SQL $wpdb-> is replaced with 'wp_'. How can I get this SQL query to work with the parse_query hook?

```
public function filter_request_query( $query ) {
  //modify the query only if it admin and main query.
  if( !( is_admin() AND $query->is_main_query() ) ) {
    return $query;
  }

  $post_type = 'product';
  $term_id = 492;

  global $wpdb;
  $results = $wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->get_results( "
      SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} t2 WHERE t2.post_type = %s AND t2.ID IN
      (SELECT post_parent FROM {$wpdb->posts} t1, {$wpdb->term_relationships} t3
      WHERE t1.ID IN
      (SELECT t3.`object_id`
      WHERE t3.`term_taxonomy_id`= %d))
      ORDER BY ID", $post_type, $term_id) );
  return $results;
}

add_filter('parse_query', 'filter_request_query', 10);
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use SQL queries in wordpress and especially Woocommerce. Can you tell me the end goal of the query, i can give you a non SQL version of the same and you can use that in the custom filter.

Comment: That's ok, I will work on a non SQL version. It is possible to use SQL for complex queries otherwise they wouldn't have the function available.

Comment: The goal is to filter products that are parents of a custom post type with a certain taxonomy value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to modify the query_vars of the original query. Using $wpdb most likely isn't possible using this filter. The ids of the parent are retrieved with `WP_Query`, and moved into an array. The `query_vars` are modified to include these ids using `post__in`

```
  //modify the query_vars.
  $sub_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_pt',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'custom_tax',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'term'
      )
    ),
    'fields' => 'id=>parent'
  ));

  $temp = [];
  foreach( $sub_query->posts as $post_ob ) {
    $temp[] = $post_ob->post_parent;
  }

  $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $temp;
  return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The get_results don't take any variables. Hence, i updated the code like this which does take variables:

```
function filter_request_query( $query ) {
  //modify the query only if it admin and main query.
  if( !( is_admin() AND $query->is_main_query() ) ) {
    return $query;
  }

  $post_type = 'product';
  $term_id = 492;

    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} t2 WHERE t2.post_type = %s AND t2.ID IN 
            (SELECT post_parent FROM {$wpdb->posts} t1, {$wpdb->term_relationships} t3 WHERE t1.ID IN 
                (SELECT t3.`object_id` from {$wpdb->term_relationships} WHERE t3.`term_taxonomy_id`= %d)
            ) ORDER BY ID", $post_type, $term_id
        )
    );
    return $results;
}

add_filter('parse_query', 'filter_request_query', 10);
```

It's running without any errors. I don't know about the results as I don't have the same environment with similar data to test. I've checked it with the [query monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin and found that it is executing the hook and function in the theme.

**OLD ANSWER**

So, i tested this query on one of my woocommerce databases and found out that the query is not correct.

Here's the correct query without syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} t2 WHERE t2.post_type = %s AND t2.ID IN
      (SELECT post_parent FROM {$wpdb->posts} t1, {$wpdb->term_relationships} t3
      WHERE t1.ID IN
      (SELECT t3.`object_id` from {$wpdb->term_relationships}
      WHERE t3.`term_taxonomy_id`= %d))
      ORDER BY ID", $post_type, $term_id) );
```

The **from {$wpdb->term_relationships}** was missing in the 3rd SELECT query and hence it was giving a syntax error. I added it and it started executing in my PhpMyAdmin.

Hope your code works after this fix as that looks correct to me.

Comment: If you test it in wordpress does it work? I'm still getting a syntax error.

Comment: Hey! I've updated the code and it seems to not give any error. Can you test it and let me know if that solves your syntax error?

Comment: It runs without error, but for some reason. It doesn't change the original query when it's returned. I checked the contents of $results and it's 71.

Comment: I used a non SQL version as I couldn't get the SQL version to work. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It'd be great if you could post your solution here so that anyone else looking for a solution can use it. I'll include that in my answer too.

Comment: I posted the solution. You shouldn't modify your answer, as it'll be a duplicate of the solution and could cause confusion.